# Css tableless forms with flexible label

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, label

I have admin site, that contains lots of forms, that are tend to be styled via aligning to label:

```
<form>
    <label for="name"><input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="name"><input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="name"><input type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

What i usually do to get the effect:

```
label{
    width: 150px /* fixed that is */
    text-align: right;
}
```

This works well, but not when my multiple forms, have sometimes very different, and longer label name, which in result forces me to give the minimum required width, for biggest elements, if i want all forms to align perfectly in vertical line. But when there's little of content, the big gap is comming, and results are overall not flexible enough.

Does anyone have idea for solution to this problem? Css or jQuery (not sure if it's effective) maybe? But my idea for jQuery would be looping .width() from specific form (there are sometimes few different forms on same page), and picking max from it, then asigning it as width to their parent but that seem like a troublesome solution.

Comment: It would be trivial to create that in jQuery. P.S. are you sure you don't just should use a table?

Comment: It gives me more flexibility, cause sometimes i want my form to be horizontal only, and sometimes purely vertical, which makes me wanna keep my html as clean as possible

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about this...

Using percentage widths and float: left.  Long labels will wrap onto multiple lines (this is not exactly what you were asking for, I know).

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label for="name">lka;sjdl kfa jsldkkfjlkasdjf alkdsjalkfk asdfasd asd fasdf dfdsa afsd afdsf asdfsdads jdaslk </label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="name">ljlkjljljljljlkj</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="name">asdfasfdsasdaf</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    width:400px;
}
label {
    width: 48%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
input {
    width: 48%; 
    float: left;
}
```

I find you need to have the total widths adding up to fractionally less than 100%, to account for inherited borders and margins etc. I determined that 49% would work by trial and error.

Tested in Firefox only.